Is there any law to reference to support copyright derivation wrt software libraries depending on the availability of alternatives?
In a 2019 answer that the bot has just pumped there is an excellent description of a way I have heard how the the rules regarding copyright derivation in respect to software libraries function:

I don't know if software that imports/includes other software is considered "derivative", but legally it probably has to do with the ability of your software to use another module that performs similar functionality. If your software calls an API which is instantiated in multiple libraries, then it probably isn't derivative. If the API is unique enough to a specific library, then a court might rule it "derivative". For example, I have a program that uses either BSD-licensed Editline, or GPL-licensed GNU Readline. My understanding is that because the API that I use is the same for both, installing my software on a machine that uses Readline doesn't mean my software must be GPL. Please note that I could be wrong.

I read this to mean if Editline did not exist, and the only implementation of this API was provided by Readline, then the source code of "my software" would be a derivative product of Readline.  This would require me to also distribute the source code of "my software" under the GPL if I was to distribute the binary.  The very existence of Editline, even though I did not use it, removes this requirement.
My understanding is that the logic here is something like that because my source code contains text such as "get_line_buffer()", if get_line_buffer() only means the exact right thing in respect to GNU Readline then my code is a derivative of GNU Readline.  If get_line_buffer() means the exact right thing in both GNU Readline and non-copyleft BSD licenced Editline then my code is not derivative of either.
Is there anything we could quote to support (or refute) this statement that is more authoritative that open source advocates saying it online?  Is this based on laws as written, judgements or legal theories by respected legal scholars?

I  think that you mean "derivative works" rather than "derivation works" but I am not editing the question, in case you are referring to something else with which I am not familiar.

@Jen In software, when an application uses a library, the code of the application and library are combined into a single executable file (this is called linking). This executable is considered to be derived from both the application source code and the library. And since the appliction source by itself is meaningless until it's compiled and linked, it's considered effectively derived from the libraries it needs.

But if there are multiple libraries that can be linked, it's not considered derived from any specific one of them.

@ohwilleke I have clarified the first paragraph.

@Barmar sure, but that isn't necessarily combined in the distributed code, or in the source code, or even in the distributed binary (if linking is dynamic). I don't have any questions about the nature of code or linking. This question just isn't clear about which artifact they want examined for its derivative-ness.

@Jen I know that. But for whatever reason, we tend to ignore the difference between dynamic and static linking -- it's a technicality that doesn't change the effective relationship between the components.

@Jen "This question just isn't clear about which artifact they want examined for its derivative-ness" The sentence that I hoped made that clear is "This would require me to also distribute the source code of "my software" under the GPL if I was to distribute the binary." The artefact in question is the source code of "my software".  I can try an improve it if you think that is better, but it is pushing my knowledge.

This seems legally problematic and trivially defeatable (eg, if I have a non-functioning version of the API, does that mean the application is now non-derived?).  The referenced question seems to have shades of the views of the GPL authors as referenced in this answer, however note that for purposes of that point of view it wouldn't matter whether there were multiple implementations of the API - as long as the linked one was referenced the GPL authors considered it infringing.

@Barmar - because it does, because usually the dynamic library is not distributed with the application (or is at arm's length, such as a separate step in the installer).  In such a case, providing an implementation of the library is left as an exercise for the sysadmin (which historically could be quite a challenge!).
